# Cannot load entity by root class in joined inheritance chain with JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the following inheritance chain:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Answer extends AbstractEntity {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "chosen_answers")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public class ChosenAnswer extends Answer {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    AnswerChoice answerChoice;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "free_text_answers")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public class FreeTextAnswer extends Answer {

    String answerText;

}
```

The (simplified) sample content of my database looks like this:

**answers:**

--ID---

| 100 |

**free_text_answers:**

--ID----answer_text--

| 100 | "Some text" |

The foreignkey from `free_text_answers(id)` to `answers(id)` is created.
The problem is that the entity manager returns `null` for the following statement:

```
em.find(Answer.class, 100l); // returns null
```

although, 100 is a valid id for a stored answer. If I query the entity manager for instances of `FreeTextAnswer`, I get the expected result.

```
em.find(FreeTextAnswer.class, 100l) // returns stored entity
```

The strange thing is, as soon as I query the entity manager for the subtype, the first statement also returns the requested entity.

Is this the expected result? If yes, how do I design my inheritance chain to work the way I like?

I am using Spring Data Rest, and I only expose the `Answer`-entity via a RestRepository, therefore Spring Data Rest calls the entity manager with an `Answer` as the expected entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further debugging with the generated SQL statements, I found a workaround to solve the problem.

As you can see in the ER diagram below, one subclass of `Answer` has a `OneToOne` relationship to another entity. The default fetchtype for such a relationship is `EAGER` which turned out to be the problem.
As soon as I configured hibernate to lazy-load this relationship, everything works as expected.

Is this a bug in hibernate?

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: interesting. btw, what tool did u used for the diagram? is that Intellij?thx

Comment: Yes, I created the diagram with IntelliJ.
IntelliJ however uses yFiles under the hood (as noted by the watermark).